# getting error that header has been already sent using Passport and Nest framework

Tags: typescript, google-oauth, passport.js, nestjs

I have a NestJS app that has some auth logic inside it. The login is implemented for Google Oauth using Passport and seems to be working except that on the server I will this error:

```
(node:19195) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

I Google'd a bit and seems like one of the common reasons might be to send the response a few times to the client. That being said, I can't spot that in my code so I'm suspicious if that's the reason. Here are the relevant snippets.

Using @nestjs/passport to serialize and deserialize user.

```
@Injectable()
export class GoogleSerializer extends PassportSerializer {
    constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {
        super();
    }

    public serializeUser(user: User, done: Function) {
        console.log('serialize', user);
        if (user) {
            done(null, user.id);
        } else {
            done(null);
        }
    }

    public async deserializeUser(id: number, done: Function) {
        console.log('deserialize', id);
        this.usersService.findById(id).then(user => {
            done(null, user);
        }).catch(error => {
            done(error, null);
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the Google strategy for the Passport JS:

```
@Injectable()
export class GoogleStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {
    super({
      clientID:
        'client',
      clientSecret: 'I'm-secret',
      callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
      scope: ['email', 'profile'],
    });
  }

  async validate(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    const user = <create the user object from google profile> 

    this.usersService.findOne(user.email).then(userEntity => {
      if (!userEntity) {
        this.usersService.createOne(user);
      }
    });
    return this.usersService
      .findOne(user.email)
      .then(user => {
        done(null, user);
        return user;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        done(error);
        return null;
      });
  }
}
```

Here is the routes for the AuthController:

```
@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  @Get('/google/callback')
  async googleCallback(@Req() req, @Res() res, @Next() next) {
    passport.authenticate('google', {
      successReturnToOrRedirect: '/users/test',
      failureRedirect: '/auth/login'
    })(req, res, next);
  }

  @Get('/login')
  async login(@Req() req) {
    return '<a href="/auth/google/login">Login</a>';
  }

  @Get('/google/login')
  async googleLogin(@Req() req, @Res() res, @Next() next) {
    passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] })(req, res, next);
  }
}
```

I have a middleware for the paths that user needs to be logged-in:

```
    @Injectable()
    export class LoginRequired implements NestMiddleware {
        resolve(...args: any[]): MiddlewareFunction {
            console.log('calling loginrequired');
            return (req, res, next) => {
                if (!req.isAuthenticated || !req.isAuthenticated()) {
                    if (req.session) {
                        req.session.returnTo = req.originalUrl || req.url;
                    }
                    return res.redirect('/auth/login');
                }
                next();
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is the setup phase:

```
app.use(session({
secret: 'secret',
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: true,
cookie: { secure: false }}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

For example, I try to go /user that is protected by this middleware and that should send the user to the login page which prompts the user to login and brings the user to the /user page. It all works but I'm getting

> Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Any ideas how that's happening?

I use Pasport js and NestJs.

Comment: Maybe this new medium article helps you mastering oauth in NestjS: https://medium.com/@nielsmeima/auth-in-nest-js-and-angular-463525b6e071

Comment: Thank you @kentor. I will take a look. The only thing is they are using JWT instead of session/cookie based approach which I'm not totally sure it's the best approach for the typical auth for an app.

Comment: I don't see how JWT conflicts with session/cookie. JWTs are literally a way to issue JSON content from the server to the client including a guarantee that no one can tamper this token. JWTs are basically signed JSONs and the signature will fail if someone has changed the content - that's it. You would still store in a HTTPS only cookie or session storage.

Comment: This way the user will send the JWT with every request to the backend and you don't need to verify the user a second time which saves lots of resources and boilerplate code